# How can I achieve this functionality to allow url prefixes without hacking the core?

Tags: uri

Lets say I have a site example.com with the following urls:

```
example.com
example.com/page1
example.com/about
```

This is an American site, but I also want an Australian version.

The urls for the Australian site will be:

```
example.com/au
example.com/au/page1
example.com/au/about
```

The homepage and `page1` are identical on both sites so the same content is served. However there is an Australian specific version of `about` so different content is served.

How can I map all of the `/au` pages to the ones without `/au` and somehow pass the fact that it is an AU page so I can determine what content to serve?

---

**Update:**

To clarify I want every single page that exists to be accessible via it's normal path alias, or the normal path alias prefixed with "au/".

I have managed to achieve this by editing bootstrap.inc in the following way:

A. Alter [`request_path()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/request_path/7). After the line:

```
$path = substr(urldecode($request_path), $base_path_len + 1);
```

I added:

```
if(substr($path, 0, 3) == 'au/') {
  $path = substr($path, 3);
  $_SESSION['au'] = TRUE;
} else {
  $_SESSION['au'] = FALSE;
}
```

B. Alter [`drupal_settings_initialize()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_settings_initialize/7). After the `$base_path` has been set add:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['au']) && $_SESSION['au']) {
  $base_path = '/au/';    
}
```

This means both `/page` and `/au/page` are treated in exactly the same way and I can use `$_SESSION['au']` in a node preprocessor hook to determine which content to serve.

Now my question is how can I achieve this behaviour **without hacking the core?**

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/project/domain - this allow configure site as you want...

Comment: That sounds promising. I can see it can map the same drupal instance to multiple subdomains but can't see any mention of using a country code url prefix such as /au/page. Do you know if this is possible with this module?

Comment: yes, you can, read please: http://www.trellon.com/content/blog/sharing-content-domain-access - so you can create "about" for all affilliates, and "au/about" to only australian...

Comment: Yes! That is exactly what I want to achieve. Thanks for the link. Hopefully that should solve all my problems :)

Comment: Hmm, after having read most of the documentation and gone though the issue queue I'm struggling to find anything on using country code url prefixes. That blog post does mention it but does not go into enough depth to be useful and they are also using an outdated version of the module. Will continue looking...

Comment: Why dont you use the internationalization project I guess that does what you are looking for. https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n

Comment: domain provide supporting paths like /au, i18n - provide certain translation by detection this path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [i18n](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n). It does this for you.

You have the possibility to choose how the content is served (from the module configuration page), between a subdomain for ex. "au.mysite.com/post-name" and prefixes like "mysite.com/au/post-name".

You will have a language field for your content-type, and you can easily set different content for different languages.

Comment: Just got this working. Not only does it map /au/contact to /contact but also updates all links with the country code prefix. The key to getting this working was to check the *Detection and selection* settings and enable URL. Thanks for your help :)